# What program(s) can I use to open an .xlsx spreadsheet for editing on my Mac

Tags: windows, ms-office

I can double-click the file and a browser preview opens that looks like excel.... but it is basically just a browser preview feature and it is read-only.

The file came from a Windows machine.

Comment: What programs do you have on your Mac? How did you get the file onto your machine?

Comment: 1. What app are you opening the file in? Excel? Numbers? OpenOffice/LibreOffice? 2. Is the file being opened from a remote drive? From an email? From your Desktop?

Comment: i get a .xlsx file and I double click on it it opens as a browser preview, not an editable spreadsheet

Comment: looks like I should be opening it in a spreadsheet application but which one? how to choose? how to find.  If ones knows windows it is ms office and excel.  If one does NOT know a mac at all, which product to use / pick / download, etc.

Comment: If you're looking for a software recommendation, you should re-word your question. However what you probably want is [Microsoft's Office for Mac suite](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products), which includes the Mac version of Excel.

Comment: I did not know I was looking for software recommendations until trying quite a few things.  Once I did i reworded my question.  Yes open office is the answer.  Post as an answer and I'll accept and give you the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response makes a couple of assumptions:

- You just want to be able to open the document and do basic editing
- The document is essentially local to your computer
- You want a free / open source solution

You should be able to use Apache OpenOffice CALC to edit files in the Microsoft Excel file format of .xlsx as per the OpenOffice website:

> Since version 3.0, Calc has been able to read .xlsx files created with
>   Microsoft Office 2007 or Microsoft Office 2008 for Mac OS X

You may download OpenOffice from this site: http://www.openoffice.org/download/

Alternatively, you can always use the MAC version of Microsoft Office 2011 available for purchase here: http://www.microsoft.com/mac/buy

Comment: May I suggest LibreOffice instead? Most OpenOffice developers jumped ship.

Comment: Apache OpenOffice CALC does not save XLSX files! Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opened it in Excel but you are unable to select or change it, the sheet may be protected.   If the sheet has been protected using the **Tools > Protection > Protect Sheet** option then a lock symbol will appear next to the sheet name in Excel 2011.

Sheet protection can be removed by using the **Tools > Protection > Unprotect Sheet** command.